# Environment Variables with Serverless and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am learning serverless framework and I'm making a simple login system.

Here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: lms-auth

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: dev
    region: ap-south-1

environment:
    MONGODB_URI: $(file(../env.yml):MONOGDB_URI)
    JWT_SECRET: $(file(../env.yml):JWT_SECRET)

functions:
    register:
        handler: handler.register
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/register/
                  method: post
                  cors: true
    login:
        handler: handler.login
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/login/
                  method: post
                  cors: true

plugins:
    - serverless-offline
```

As you can see, I have two environment variables and both of them are referencing to a different file in the same root folder.

Here is that env.yml file

```
MONOGDB_URI: <MY_MONGO_DB_URI>
JWT_SECRET: LmS_JWt_secREt_auth_PasSWoRds
```

When I do `sls deploy`, I see that both the variables are logging as null. The environment variables aren't sent to lambda.

How can I fix this?

Also, currently I'm using this method and adding the `env.yml` to `.gitignore` and saving the values. Is there any other efficient way of hiding sensitive data?

Comment: You write "different file in the same root folder." but the file where you read the envs from is the same. Can you share your directory structure as well? Is the env.yml in the parent folder from serverless.yml?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this to help you out with the syntax

```
service: lms-auth

custom: ${file(env.yml)}
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: dev
    region: ap-south-1

environment:
    MONGODB_URI: ${self:custom.mongodb_uri}
    JWT_SECRET: ${self:custom.jwt_secret}

functions:
    register:
        handler: handler.register
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/register/
                  method: post
                  cors: true
    login:
        handler: handler.login
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/login/
                  method: post
                  cors: true

plugins:
- serverless-offline
```

Then in your env.yml you can do

```
mongodb_uri: MY_MONGO_DB_URI
jwt_secret: LmS_JWt_secREt_auth_PasSWoRds
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enviroment variables](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables)

1. Add useDotenv:true to your `.yml` file 
2.Add your variables like this -> `${env:VARIABLE_NAME}`
3.Create a file called `.env.dev` and write the variables (You can add `.env.prod` but you have to change the stage inside your `.yml` file )
 **Example :**

```
service: lms-auth

useDotenv: true

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs12.x
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1

    environment:
        MONGODB_URI: ${env:MONOGDB_URI}
        JWT_SECRET: ${env:JWT_SECRET}

functions:
    register:
        handler: handler.register
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/register/
                  method: post
                  cors: true
    login:
        handler: handler.login
        events:
            - http:
                  path: auth/login/
                  method: post
                  cors: true

plugins:
    - serverless-offline
```

**.env.dev**

```
MONOGDB_URI = The URI Value 
JWT_SECRET = The JWT Scret Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it.  I had set up my Dynamo DB in AWS us-west region.  reinitialized in US-East-2, and reset the region under 'provider' within the .yml file.